# Install Openstack Kilo using the OpenStack Autopilot?

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Is there a way to install Kilo Openstack using the openstack installer?
[Build OpenStack with conjure-up | Download | Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)

Is there a way to do it without using a box for landscape with kilo? one of the 3 options is multi,landscape, single. 
http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multi-installer.guide.html

Does the MaaS machine need to be ubuntu 15.04, or just the images that the nodes go to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the Vancouver OpenStack Summit, it was [indicated](https://youtu.be/-HjKHD5rv7A?t=24m4s) the plan is for Kilo to be supported by the Landscape Autopilot in July.

Of course, Kilo packages are available today, and you can build an Autopilot-less OpenStack yourself, just without the enhanced user experience of the guided setup.